# fetchmail to log complete messages AND pass to mda

Tags: email, smtp, fetchmail, imap

I couldn't seem to tell from the `fetchmail` man page or http://www.catb.org/~esr/fetchmail/fetchmail-man.html#7 whether `--bsmtp <filename>.bsmtp.log`, applied from cli/cronjob, and `--mda <command>` applied from varying *fetchmailrc* config files are mutually exclusive.

I am hoping not as I am trying to keep a "filename.bsmtp.log" for failover purposes on dedicated machine-email accounts, among all other fetchmail parameters to limit which messages are retrieved and how/if they are left on the IMAP server.  Most of the messages the mda simply tosses so it is hard to tell if they've been seen or not properly by the mda.  It is custom built and designed to exit immediately with no reading** under certain conditions, for example in the presence of certain other processes on the appliance.

If they are mutually exclusive, is there another way to log everything similar to --bsmtp, in fetchmail, without altering the custom built mda?

**Deliberately putting the responsibility back on `fetchmail` to not dismiss that message as read. Experimentally confirmed when the mda's *stdin* was not read until *EOF* before exiting

Comment: An alternative to `fetchmail` as a layer would be fine too

Comment: Can you insert another MDA between fetchmail and the real MDA (a simple thing with `tee`)?

Comment: I considered that too, making a simple wrapper that logs before handing off/exec to the real MDA. The trouble is that mucks with the stdout of fetchmail, which sometimes I count on leaving unread partially or at all (the fetchmail side of the pipe sees where the seek pointer left off...)